# How can I hide HTML tags?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using a form to post to a blog. On the blog show post page I use the == on the rails content display tag to interpret the html.

However, I have a blog index page which shows the latest posts, I want the truncated post previews to not interpret the html but at the same time hide the html tags.

How can i do this?

```
  def blog
    #@content3 = Content.find(3)
    @blogPosts = Blogpost.all.reverse.drop(1)
    @latestPost = Blogpost.last
    if @latestPost.blank? == false
      @blogPicture = Blogpost.last.image
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render :layout => 'blog' }
    end
  end
```

Comment: Please let us see your code.

Comment: <%= truncate(@latestPost.content, :length => 200, :separator => ' ') %>

Comment: added controller code to main thread :)

Comment: so you want to show a truncated preview without html tags? am i getting this right ?

Comment: Correct :) Without the HTML working

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `full_sanitizer` and then `truncate` result.

Example (used in controller):

```
sanitized = ActionView::Base.full_sanitizer.sanitize(@string)
@truncated = ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper.truncate(sanitized, length: 17)
```